# Numeric(precision,decimal) equivalent in ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a sql statement :

```
Declare @res numeric(30,10)
Declare @num1 numeric(30,10) = 233.6108200000
Declare @num2 numeric(30,10) = 200000.0000000000
Declare @num3 numeric(30,10) = 0.8341
set @res = ((@num1/@num2) * 10000 * @num3)
select @res
```

**o/p : 9.7427050000**

But in ssrs expression if I try to convert :

```
=CDec((233.6108200000/200000.0000000000) * 10000 * 0.8341)
```

**o/p : 9.74273925**

Edit
What changes I need to make to ssrs expression/textbox properties to match with sql server results?

Comment: SSRS doesn't have scales and precisions. If you need to use explicit scales and precisions, you'll want to use something other than a SSRS Expression.

Comment: Or any changes in textbox properties?

Comment: Changing the format presented doesn't add lost scale. `1.235` formatted using `#,0.00000` would be `1.23500` it doesn't give "back" the digits lost already.

Comment: The simple answer is somewhere in there, floating point math is happening.  I suspect in the second one. Floating point math stores numbers as approximations instead of accurate values.  I would try casting the numbers in the second version to numeric types, same as you did in the first one, and see if that fixes it.  If not, then keep looking until you find where the floats are happening and eliminate them in both queries.

Comment: @Larnu : ok , then what is the solution for this then?

Comment: *"you'll want to use something other than a SSRS Expression"*

Comment: Actually, I think you want the SQL to match SSRS. SSRS is (more) correct. Try changing 200000 to 20 and 10000 to 1 and run the SQL.

Comment: This discrepancy exists between sql server and excel formula as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a position to test this. But I suspect that in this expression

> =CDec((233.6108200000/200000.0000000000) * 10000 * 0.8341)

some or all the numbers are interpreted as floating point numbers, which results in floating-point arithmetic. I suspect you need something more along the lines of this expression to force decimal (numeric) arithmetic.

```
= (CDec(233.6108200000)/CDec(200000.0000000000)) * CDec(10000) * CDec(0.8341)
```